# Amazon Web scrapping:Error Message: no such element: unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a class project using BeautifulSoup and webdriver to scrape Disposable Diapers on amazon for the name of the item, price, reviews, rating.

My goal is to have something like this:

```
       Diapers Size 4, 150 Count - Pampers Swaddlers Disposable Baby Diapers, One Month Supply
       4.0 out of 5 stars
       1,982
       $43.98
      ($0.29/Count)
```

Unfortunately, I get this message after the 50 data appears:

> message: no such element: unable to locate element: {"method":"css 
>          selector","selector":".a-last"}

Here is my code:

```
    URL = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=baby+disposable&rh=n%3A166772011&ref=nb_sb_noss"
    driver = ('C:/Users/Desktop/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(URL)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Product Name","Rating","Number of Reviews","Price","Price Count"])

    while True:
      for i in soup.find_all(class_= "sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 s-result-item sg-col-
      4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"):
      ProductName = i.find(class_= "a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal").text#.span.get_text
      print(ProductName)
      try:
      Rating = i.find(class_= "a-icon-alt").text#.span.get_text()
      except:
         Rating = "Null"
        print(Rating)
        try:
       NumberOfReviews = i.find(class_= "a-size-base").text#.span.get_text()
       except:
       NumberOfReviews = "Null"
       print(NumberOfReviews)
       try:
       Price = i.find(class_= "a-offscreen").text#.span.get_text()
       except:
       Price = "Null"
       print(Price)
       try:
       PriceCount = i.find(class_= "a-size-base a-color-secondary").text#.span.get_text()
       except:
       PriceCount = "Null"
       print(PriceCount)
       df = df.append({"Product Name":ProductName, "Rating":Rating, "Number of Reviews":NumberOfReviews, 
      "Price":Price, "Price Count":PriceCount}, ignore_index = True)
       nextlink = soup.find(class_= "a-disabled a-last")
       if nextlink:
       print ("This is the last page. ")
       break
       else:
       progress = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
       subhtml = driver.page_source
       soup = BeautifulSoup(subhtml, "html.parser")
```

Unfortunately, I hit a block road trying to figure out why it is not taking `a_last`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs since the webelement has not been loaded on the webpage yet. 
Before performing action on a webelement you need to ensure that element exists/loaded on webpage. 
How do you do this?
By implementing various methods to synchronize/wait. **Implicit, Explicit, Fluent** Wait- You could use any of these methods to wait for the 'a-last' to appear first and then click on it. 
For your code, you could use explicit wait:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    WebElement elementToClick = wait.until(ExpectedConditions. elementToBeClickable(driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-last');
    elementToClick.click();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashwini for you answer. the code did work after setting up a sleep time.